# Printer list for Windows Vista

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-vista, printer, print-drivers

I am trying to install an old printer into Windows 7.  The original driver, which worked in XP, won't install in 7; I understand that there were internal changes starting with Vista.  Windows 7 does not show the "Epson Stylus COLOR" (no numbers at the end of its name) in its "add a printer" list.  So I was wondering whether anyone can tell me whether this printer is in ***Vista's*** "add a printer" list.  I could not find the list online.

**Edit:**

**TL; DR,** Does the printer driver for the "Epson Stylus COLOR" (no numbers at the end of its name) come with Windows Vista?

Comment: There are many Epson Stylus Colour Printers including newer ones, so you need to find the model number. Older ones do not appear to go past XP. Newer ones have more modern drivers.

Comment: Install XP mode in Windows 7 and install the printer in XP mode.>>>>>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002

Comment: @John This machine has no extra numbers; it is only "Epson Stylus COLOR": [link](https://spectrum.ieee.org/consumer-electronics/gadgets/the-consumer-electronics-hall-of-fame-epson-stylus-color)

Comment: It is probably, then, too old to be useful today.  You should replace it.

Comment: @Moab Thank you, I thought about that.  But if Vista has a proper driver, then that should work just fine.

Comment: @John This 25-year old printer is probably the most reliable device I've ever owned.  It has needed only cleanings in all that time and prints just fine.  I am trying to keep it out of the landfill and on my desktop.

Comment: If Vista had the driver W7 will also, chances there is no compatible driver for Vista or W7 for that ancient printer.

Comment: @Moab  I see your point.  However, if I click the Windows Update button on the add a printer box, it eventually shows the Epson Stylus Color 1520 in the list, which came out only 3 years later than my printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually installed Windows Vista on a spare hard drive.  Vista does not come with the driver for that printer.

However, I noticed it does come with the driver for the Epson Stylus COLOR 1520, which is similar and came out about 2 years after my printer did.  I tried this 1520 driver on a 32-bit Windows XP machine which was connected to my printer and it printed text and 360 dpi-resolution pictures (the 720 dpi mode of my printer didn't work with that 1520 driver).